# Extracting Bank Data for given sheet in python pandas using schwifty library

Tags: pandas, conditional-formatting, np

I do have a question, hoping you can provide me some support.
Suppose you have following frame (Existing Exce-File)

```
Bank details    Bank Keys    Bank Account number    IBAN
SE              950          00099602600124545      SE9495000099602600124545
NO              DNBANOKK     15031641192            NaN
NO              DNBANOKK     70580661481            NaN
DE              20070024     0653330100             DE49200700240653330100
```

My goal is to extract the Bank Keys, Bank Account number from the IBAN data (overwrite the exisiting data inside Bank Keys and Bank Account number) only if IBAN is given, i.e. if IBAN column is not empty. My approach is following

```
import pandas as pd
from schwifty import IBAN

df["BANKL"]=np.where(df["IBAN"].isna()==False,IBAN(Vendor_Master["IBAN"]).bank_code,df["BANKL"])
```

However, if I use this like I get the following error

```
expected string or bytes-like objec
```

So then I tried the following line

```
df.loc[Vendor_Master["IBAN"].isna()==False,"BANKL"]=IBAN(df["IBAN"]).bank_code
```

Again I get the same error

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

Finally, to verify my assumption that the issue is due to the fact that the IBAN class only work on item rather than a column was to print the following line

```
print(IBAN(df["IBAN"]).bank_code)
expected string or bytes-like object
```

Question: Any support / advice how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`IBAN` only takes a single string as an argument, not a `Series`, so you need to `apply` it:

```
m = df.IBAN.notna()
cols = ['Bank details', 'Bank Keys', 'Bank Account number']

def get_bank_and_account(iban):
    iban = IBAN(iban)
    return pd.Series([iban.country_code, iban.bic.bank_code + iban.bic.country_code + iban.bic.location_code, iban.account_code.lstrip('0')], index=cols)

df.loc[m, cols] = df.loc[m, 'IBAN'].apply(get_bank_and_account)
```

Comment: Hi Stef,
thanks a lot. THis works, however if there is an empty field you get an error. I could find a work-around for that :)

Answer (score 0):

following solution helped me. The solution also considers the situation if a field is empty and error might occur

```
Bank_Code_List=[]
for iban_value, bankkey_value in zip(df["IBAN"].values,df["BANKL"].values):
                    if iban_value!="nan":
                        try:
                            Bank_Code_List.append(IBAN(iban_value).bank_code)
                        except:
                            Bank_Code_List.append("Wrong IBAN")
                    else:
                        Bank_Code_List.append(bankkey_value)
                
                df["BANKL"]=Bank_Code_List
                Bank_Code_List.clear()
```